PLSQL object collection with bulk collect
im trying to create a plsql function that response user details based on the request user type , id and name. the requirement need to be like this .
data :{ 
"types" : [
      "type" : "new",
      "accounts" : [
              {"id" : 1,
              "name" : test},
              {"id" : 2,
              "name" : test2}
],
 [
      "type" : "old",
      "accounts" : [
              {"id" : 1,
              "name" : test},
              {"id" : 2,
              "name" : test2}
]

]
}

the response will be like this
 data :{ 
    "types" : [
          "type" : "new",
          "accounts" : [
                  {"id" : 1,
                  "name" : test , address : address},
                  {"id" : 2,
                  "name" : test2 , address : address}
    ],
     [
          "type" : "old",
          "accounts" : [
                  {"id" : 1,
                  "name" : test , "address" , address},
                  {"id" : 2,
                  "name" : test2 , "address" : address}
    ]
    
    ]
    }

i already created the object for response and request. For the request i already create the plsql block to validate from the table. but for the response i kinda stuck and i dont know how to do it. can you guys help me. ill also leave the plsql request block.
DECLARE
    n_acctype        varchar2(2);  
    n_idno        number(12);
    n_count         number(20);

BEGIN

    FOR i IN 1..pi_req.acctype.COUNT LOOP
    n_acctype := pi_req.acctype(i).acctype;
    END LOOP;
    
    IF n_actype = 'new' THEN
        FOR i IN 1..pi_req.acctype('new').account.COUNT LOOP
            n_idno := pi_req.acctype('new').account(i).idno;
            
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n_count
                    FROM user01
                    WHERE idno = n_idno;
         END LOOP 
    
    END IF;

END;

is the request correct ? and how do i do the response. i didnt include the object. i dont want to make it long.
